# ST_DistanceSphere and KNN discrepancy

Tags: postgis, st-distance, knn

I have a table containing thousands of data points around London.

I'm trying to write a query to find the closest data points to a given latitude and longitude.

I'm getting different results based on whether I order by the `<->` distance operator or the result of `ST_DistanceSphere`. Here are the two queries and their results:

---

```
Order By <->
------------
SELECT 
uid,
ST_DistanceSphere(
  ST_PointFromText('POINT(-0.186243362115208 51.5128590051459)', 4326),
  the_geom
) as d
FROM points 
ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-0.186243362115208, 51.5128590051459), 4326) LIMIT 5;
```

Results:

```
  uid   |         st_astext          |       d
---------+----------------------------+---------------
6997685 | POINT(-0.186723 51.500052) | 1424.46281677
6997684 | POINT(-0.187011 51.500056) | 1424.62219563
6997686 | POINT(-0.186435 51.500047) | 1424.69367394
6997683 | POINT(-0.187299 51.500061) | 1424.94947768
6997687 | POINT(-0.186147 51.500043) |    1425.09232
```

---

```
Order By ST_DistanceSphere
--------------------------
SELECT 
uid,
ST_DistanceSphere(
  ST_PointFromText('POINT(-0.186243362115208 51.5128590051459)', 4326),
  the_geom
) as d
FROM points 
ORDER BY d LIMIT 5;
```

Results:

```
   uid   |         st_astext          |       d
---------+----------------------------+---------------
6997686 | POINT(-0.186435 51.500047) | 1424.69367394
6997685 | POINT(-0.186723 51.500052) | 1424.46281677
6997687 | POINT(-0.186147 51.500043) |    1425.09232
6997688 | POINT(-0.185859 51.500039) | 1425.76968591
6997684 | POINT(-0.187011 51.500056) | 1424.62219563
```

As you can see, the first query returns `6997683` in the results, but the second query does not (and returns `6997688` instead). `6997683` is the closer value of the two, so `6997688` should not be returned by either query.

The type of `the_geom` is `ST_Point` and the SRID (checked with `Find_SRID`) is `4326`.

What might be causing the difference, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `Order By ST_DistanceSphere` result is obviously wrong... what if you put the order by in a query, with the rest in a subquery `select * from (select uid, [...])a order by d LIMIT 5`. But actually that should not be necessary.

Comment: I think it's the other way around. Filtering by `ST_DistanceSphere` returns points that are closer (in terms of Earth Distance) than filtering by `<->`. However I am now using a subquery :-)

Comment: Where’s the documentation for <->

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because `<->` uses `ST_Distance`, as when I order explicitly by `ST_Distance` I get the same results.

I have amended my query to this:

```
SELECT 
  points.*,
  ST_AsText(points.geolocation) as geolocation, 
  ST_DistanceSphere(points.geolocation, ST_Point(:x, :y)) as distance

FROM (
  SELECT * FROM points ORDER BY geolocation <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(:x, :y),4326) LIMIT 50
) as points

ORDER BY ST_DistanceSphere(points.geolocation, ST_Point(:x, :y)) LIMIT 5
```

I make use of the efficiency of `<->` to narrow down my results to the 'nearest' 50, and then filter this list by the more accurate `ST_DistanceSphere`. And I think it gives me the results I want.