# Documentation for <->

Tags: postgis, postgresql, knn, st-distance, amazon-redshift

I found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265525/st-distancesphere-and-knn-discrepancy) question and am wondering, is it for PostgreSQL? Where’s the documentation for `<->`? Trying to find the fastest way to get the distance between a lat and long earth coordinates in Redshift.

Answer (score 9):

You'll find an exhaustive overview of supported operators in the PostGIS *[Function reference](https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html)* under *[Operators](https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Operators)*.

The more or less canonically named *spatial (K)NN* operator [`<->`](https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Operators) is documented under *[Distance operators](https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#operators-distance)*.

---

Note that this is an extension to the core distance operator shipped with PostgreSQL. This and its sibling operators are implemented with conditional access a to a suitable index (supporting *(K)NN* traversal) if put into the `ORDER BY` clause - and only this implementation detail is the primary performance advantage over plain distance functions!

For spatial distances in the PostGIS extension environment, the operator either returns 2D cartesian distances (`GEOMETRY`) or *spherical* (*great-circle*) distances (`GEOGRAPHY`).